# Why am I getting 36619 killed error on npm run build for my nuxt app?

Tags: nginx, server, nuxt.js, debian

I'm trying to deploy a nuxt app to an nginx server on a Debian machine, but when I run `npm run build`, it invariably ends up with the error `36619 killed` at about 90% of the client build process after taking a lot longer than on my regular system.

Nginx version : 1.18.0

Linux version : Debian 11

Nuxt version : 2.15.8

Comment: Does it work on your system (if you build and run it locally)? What are the hardware specs of the Debian machine?

Answer (score 0):

Found out why, the server didn't have enough ram

Comment: Yep, was about to post that after your feedback on your hardware specs. This is the most common cause of a build error when deployed on a VPS. Please accept your own answer when you will be able to.